# Meteorjs loop on id and get object

Tags: meteor

I have a collection A which have an embedded array of different IDs.
These IDs are id of collection B.

How can I loop inside a template to all of these B's id and get the associated  ?

**A template :**

```
<template name="Atemplate">
  <h1>Name of A : {{name}}</h1>
  {{#each Bs}}
      {{> Btemplate}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

**B template :**

```
<template name="Btemplate">
  <h1>Name of B : {{name}}</h1>
</template>
```

**what about B template.js ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question right, the context for `Btemplate` is an `id`. So in the `name` helper you could find the document by that `id` like so:

```js
Template.Btemplate.helpers({
  name: function() {
    var doc = B.findOne(String(this));
    return doc && doc.name;
  }
});
```

Alternatively (and someone preferably) is to set the `Btemplate` context to an instance of a `B`:

```js
Template.Atemplate.helpers({
  allBs: function() {
    return B.find({_id: {$in: this.Bs}});
  }
});
```

You'd need to modify you `A template` code as follows:

```html
{{#each allBs}}
  {{> Btemplate}}
{{/each}}
```

And now you don't need to modify the original implementation of `Btemplate`. I'd also recommend reading the templates articles from [here](https://www.discovermeteor.com/encyclopedia).

Comment: I used the preferably solution you exposed : It's work ! Thank a lot.